# IGListKit - Dynamic .minimumLineSpacing within a IGListSectionController

Tags: ios, iglistkit

I have a section controller "mySectionController"
with 3 different cells inside

- A
- B
- C

I want to apply `.minimumLineSpacing` only between cell B and C

- A
- B
- (space 10p)
- C

If I set the `.minimumLineSpacing` in the init of my controller, obviously the space is applied to all my cells.

I could add a space in my B cell, but i was looking for a clean solution.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you are going to need to make a section controller for A, B and C. and set the section insets for `sectionControllerB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably recommend adding 10pts of spacing to your actual cell in this case. Create a sizing class function on your cell that returns the preferred size + 10, then in `layoutSubviews` just subtract 10 from the bounds height.

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` isn't designed to have variable line spacing, so we modeled IGListKit after that:

https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Source/IGListAdapter.m#L1167-L1170

It wouldn't be impossible to write your own layout and hook into IGListKit to make this work, however I think using the cell padding "trick" above would be a whole lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks rnystrom! I ended up doing that. - PS. I'm following IGListKit progress on Github, great job man! You and jessesquires rocks! :)